# How can I parse a raw HTTP response in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, http

I've got a project which deals with byte streams, and some of them are HTTP responses. I need to parse a raw HTTP response from this byte stream.

I can do this myself, but there must already be code that exists to do this, so I started looking at [Kestrel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel/), but I can't see any way to do what I'm attempting. Perhaps it's overkill for my needs any way.

How can I parse a raw HTTP response in .net?

Here's an example, decoded to ASCII:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Sun, 17 Apr 2022 03:32:06 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "374b9ab6b52d81:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 27 Apr 2022 10:45:49 GMT
Content-Length: 696

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>IIS Windows</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#0072C6;
    margin:0;
}

#container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    }

a img {
    border:none;
}

-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66138&amp;clcid=0x409"><img src="iisstart.png" alt="IIS" width="960" height="600" /></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What info in response are you interested in?

Comment: @PoulBak All of it

Comment: @Dharman why did you delete my answer?

Comment: I once looked into how `HttpClient` processes responses, but I couldn't see how to reuse the parser. Mostly because the parser is optimised to leave content unread in the stream until you ask for it. The easiest workaround I could think of would be faking a web server. Bind to a loop back port, tell the http client to get some url, then immediately pipe the pre-canned response to the stream.

Comment: FYI I believe that parsing a http 1.1 response starts here; https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cb10ed9430762f63a4e9b23a25d142b3ff909879/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs#L596

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this Nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpMachine.PCL/4.0.3

```
using (var handler = new HttpParserDelegate())
using (var parser = new HttpCombinedParser(handler))
{
    bArray = TestReponse();
    Console.WriteLine(parser.Execute(bArray) == bArray.Length
        ? $"Reponse test succeed. Type identified is; {handler.HttpRequestResponse.MessageType} \r\n" +
            $"Headers: \r\n" +
            $"{string.Join("\r\n", handler.HttpRequestResponse.Headers.Select(h => $"{h.Key}: {string.Join(", ", h.Value)} "))}"
        : $"Response test failed");

    handler.HttpRequestResponse.Body.Position = 0;
    var reader = new StreamReader(handler.HttpRequestResponse.Body);
    var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpWebResponse implements ISerializable.

So you could simply deserialize your byte stream using a BinaryFormatter

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)formatter.Deserialize(sourceByteStream);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting but this code produces a very prominent warning not to use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide